# Unequal vertical spacing when using bmatrix inside a table

Tags: tables, amsmath, matrices, siunitx, booktabs

I have a table containing a column of `bmatrix` with `siunitx` units. I've noticed the vertical spacing of the first matrix is different to the others. Is it possible for all rows to be equally spaced **without** having to adjust the spacing manually?

```
\usepackage{amsmath, booktabs}
...
\begin{table*}
    \centering
    \begin{tabular}{cccc}
        \toprule
        Configuration    & $m$                     & $\rho_{3}$               & $I$                                                                                                                                                                       \\
        \midrule
        No Mass        & \SI{67.07}{\gram} & \SI{6.65}{\milli\metre}  & $\begin{bmatrix}
                                                                                         \num[round-mode=figures, round-precision=2]{3.314e-5} & 0                                                      & 0                                                      \\
                                                                                         0                                                     & \num[round-mode=figures, round-precision=2]{3.114e-05} & 0                                                      \\
                                                                                         0                                                     & 0                                                      & \num[round-mode=figures, round-precision=2]{1.386e-05} \\
                                                                                     \end{bmatrix}$\si{\kilogram\per\square\meter} \\

        +\SI{100}{\gram} & \SI{166.03}{\gram} & \SI{49.16}{\milli\metre} & $\begin{bmatrix}
                                                                                         \num[round-mode=figures, round-precision=2]{1.3215e-4} & 0                                                      & 0                                                      \\
                                                                                         0                                                      & \num[round-mode=figures, round-precision=2]{1.3009e-4} & 0                                                      \\
                                                                                         0                                                      & 0                                                      & \num[round-mode=figures, round-precision=2]{4.561e-05} \\
                                                                                     \end{bmatrix}$\si{\kilogram\per\square\meter} \\                                                    \\
        +\SI{200}{\gram} & \SI{215.61}{\gram} & \SI{50.01}{\milli\metre} & $\begin{bmatrix}
                                                                                         \num[round-mode=figures, round-precision=2]{1.6936e-4} & 0                                                      & 0                                                      \\
                                                                                         0                                                      & \num[round-mode=figures, round-precision=2]{1.6728e-4} & 0                                                      \\
                                                                                         0                                                      & 0                                                      & \num[round-mode=figures, round-precision=2]{7.732e-05} \\
                                                                                     \end{bmatrix}$\si{\kilogram\per\square\meter} \\                                                   \\
        +\SI{300}{\gram} & \SI{315.26}{\gram} & \SI{50.48}{\milli\metre} & $\begin{bmatrix}
                                                                                         \num[round-mode=figures, round-precision=2]{2.022e-4} & 0                                                      & 0                                                      \\
                                                                                         0                                                     & \num[round-mode=figures, round-precision=2]{2.0013e-4} & 0                                                      \\
                                                                                         0                                                     & 0                                                      & \num[round-mode=figures, round-precision=2]{1.0902e-4} \\
                                                                                     \end{bmatrix}$\si{\kilogram\per\square\meter}  \\                                                    \\
        \bottomrule
    \end{tabular}
    \caption{Table of all the follower mass configurations, with the parameters for follower mass $m$ and follower \ac{COM} z offset $\rho_{3}$.}
    \label{table:masses}
\end{table*}
```

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Is it possible for all rows to be equally spaced without having to adjust the spacing manually?

I'm not sure I understand what you mean by "adjusting the spacing manually". I suggest that you use `\addlinespace` directives at the end of each line, rather than `\\ \\` in some cases and `\\` in others.

I would also simplify and streamline the appearance of the table by moving everything that's repeated on each line -- such as the units of measurement -- into the table's header. Aligning the numbers in columns 2 and 3 on their respective decimal markers would add a nice touch as well.

[image]

```
\documentclass[twocolumn]{article} % or some other suitable document class
\usepackage{amsmath, booktabs, siunitx, threeparttable, array}
\sisetup{round-mode=places, round-precision=2, 
         per-mode=symbol, exponent-product = \cdot}
         
\begin{document}

\begin{table*}
\centering
\begin{threeparttable} % optional
\begin{tabular}{@{} l S[table-format=3.2] S[table-format=2.2] >{$}c<{$} @{}}
\toprule
Configuration & {$m$} & {$\rho_{3}$}  & I \\
& {[\unit{\gram}]} & {[\unit{\milli\metre}]} & [\unit{\kilogram\per\square\meter}] \\
\midrule
No Mass & 67.07 & 6.65 & 
\begin{bmatrix} 
      \num{3.314e-5} & 0  & 0  \\
      0 & \num{3.114e-05} & 0  \\
      0 & 0  & \num{1.386e-05} 
\end{bmatrix} \\ \addlinespace
+\qty[round-precision=0]{100}{\gram} & 166.03 & 49.16 & 
\begin{bmatrix}
      \num{1.3215e-4} & 0  & 0  \\
      0  & \num{1.3009e-4} & 0  \\
      0  & 0  & \num{4.561e-05} 
\end{bmatrix} \\ \addlinespace
+\qty[round-precision=0]{200}{\gram} & 215.61 & 50.01 & 
\begin{bmatrix}
      \num{1.6936e-4} & 0  & 0  \\
      0  & \num{1.6728e-4} & 0  \\
      0  & 0  & \num{7.732e-05} 
\end{bmatrix} \\ \addlinespace 
+\qty[round-precision=0]{300}{\gram} & 315.26 & 50.48 & 
\begin{bmatrix}
      \num{2.022e-4} & 0  & 0  \\
      0 & \num{2.0013e-4} & 0  \\
      0 & 0  & \num{1.0902e-4}
\end{bmatrix}  \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}

\caption{Table of all follower mass configurations, with the 
parameters for follower mass $m$ and follower COM z offset $\rho_{3}$.}
\label{table:masses}
\end{threeparttable} % optional
\end{table*}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Square brackets around the units? +1 anyway

Comment: I meant using `\\[x]` to change the row spacing, where x is a unit of length.

Comment: @Crazymoomin - I think you'll find that using `\addlinespace` is much more convenient and straightforward than coming up with a suitable value for `x` in `\\[x]` is.